# Scrapy crawl spider does not download files?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

So I am made a crawl spider which crawls this website (https://minerals.usgs.gov/science/mineral-deposit-database/#products, follows every link on that web page, from which it scrapes the title and it is suppesed to download the file as well. Howerver this does not happen and there is no error indication in the log!

**LOG SAMPLE**

```
2018-11-19 18:20:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/5a1492c3e4b09fc93dcfd574>
{'date': [datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 19, 18, 20, 12, 209865)],
'file': 
['https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/file/get/5a1492c3e4b09fc93dcfd574? 
f=__disk__d7%2F26%2Fdb%2Fd726dbd9030e7554a4ef13cb56f53983f407eb7d',

'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/file/get/5a1492c3e4b09fc93dcfd574? 
f=__disk__d7%2F26%2Fdb%2Fd726dbd9030e7554a
4ef13cb56f53983f407eb7d&transform=1',
'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/file/get/5a1492c3e4b09fc93dcfd574? 
f=__disk__72%2F6b%2F7d%2F726b7dd547ce9805a97e2464dc1f4646b2a16cfb',

'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/file/get/5a1492c3e4b09fc93dcfd574? 
f=__disk__d4%2F87%2F6b%2Fd4876b385bc9ac2af3c9221aee4ff7a5a88f201a',

'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/file/get/5a1492c3e4b09fc93dcfd574? 
f=__disk__12%2Fd9%2F4f%2F12d94f844998c4a4eaf1cedd80b70f36ed960a2c',

'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/file/get/5a1492c3e4b09fc93dcfd574? 
f=__disk__12%2Fd9%2F4f%2F12d94f844998c4a4eaf1cedd80b70f36ed960a2c',

'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/file/get/5a1492c3e4b09fc93dcfd574? 
f=__disk__e3%2Ff0%2F95%2Fe3f0958d05c1240724b58709196a87492b85d8d4',

'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/file/get/5a1492c3e4b09fc93dcfd574? 
 f=__disk__e3%2Ff0%2F95%2Fe3f0958d05c1240724b58709196a87492b85d8d4',

'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/file/get/5a1492c3e4b09fc93dcfd574? 
facet=USGS_TopoMineSymbols_ver2_mapservice.sd',

'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/file/get/5a1492c3e4b09fc93dcfd574? 
f=__disk__b0%2F64%2Fd3%2Fb064d3465149780209ef624db57830e40edb9115'],
'name': ['Prospect- and Mine-Related Features from U.S. Geological Survey '
          '7.5- and 15-Minute Topographic Quadrangle Maps of the United '
          'States'],
'project': ['us_deposits'],
'server': ['DESKTOP-9CUE746'],
'spider': ['deposits'],
'url': 
['https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/5a1492c3e4b09fc93dcfd574']}

2018-11-19 18:20:12 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 7312,
 'downloader/request_count': 23,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 23,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 615330,
 'downloader/response_count': 23,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 13,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 9,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 19, 17, 20, 12, 397317),
 'item_scraped_count': 9,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 34,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'offsite/domains': 1,
 'offsite/filtered': 2,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 13,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 19,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 19,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 19,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 19,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 19, 17, 20, 7, 541186)}
2018-11-19 18:20:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

**SPIDER**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import datetime
import socket
from us_deposits.items import DepositsusaItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import urljoin


class DepositsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'deposits'
    allowed_domains = ['doi.org']
    start_urls = ['https://minerals.usgs.gov/science/mineral-deposit-database/#products', ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="products"][1]/p/a'),
             callback='parse_x'),
    )

    def parse_x(self, response):
        i = ItemLoader(item=DepositsusaItem(), response=response)
        i.add_xpath('name', '//*[@class="container"][1]/header/h1/text()')
        i.add_xpath('file', '//span[starts-with(@data-url, "/catalog/file/get/")]/@data-url',
                    MapCompose(lambda i: urljoin(response.url, i))
                    )
        i.add_value('url', response.url)
        i.add_value('project', self.settings.get('BOT_NAME'))
        i.add_value('spider', self.name)
        i.add_value('server', socket.gethostname())
        i.add_value('date', datetime.datetime.now())
        return i.load_item()
```

**SETTINGS**

```
BOT_NAME = 'us_deposits'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['us_deposits.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'us_deposits.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'us_deposits.pipelines.UsDepositsPipeline': 1,
}

FILES_STORE = {
    'C:/Users/User/Documents/Python WebCrawling Learning Projects'
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a close look at the [Files Pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-files-pipeline) documentation:

> In a Spider, you scrape an item and put the URLs of the desired into a
>   file_urls field.

You need to store the URLs of the files to download in a field name `file_urls`, not `file`.

This minimal spider works for me:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'usgs.gov'
    allowed_domains = ['doi.org']
    start_urls = ['https://minerals.usgs.gov/science/mineral-deposit-database/#products']

    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1},
        'FILES_STORE': '/my/valid/path/',
    }

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@id="products"]/p/a'), callback='parse_x'),
    )

    def parse_x(self, response):

        yield {
            'file_urls': [response.urljoin(u) for u in response.xpath('//span[starts-with(@data-url, "/catalog/file/get/")]/@data-url').extract()],
        }
```

Comment: I changed the files _field_  to  _file_urls_ and I also created a _files_ field in the items.py . Do I need to declare it in the spider as well? If so, could you show me how? Thanks

Comment: You don't need to declare them in the spider, this is just an example

Comment: Thank you! Howerver I am not quite sure, why my spider doesn't download the files. I will check it again and update the code!